# Как получить имя атрибута товара в woocommerce

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

Подскажите, как получить имя атрибута товара в woocommerce по его (атрибута, имеется ввиду) слагу или id?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Используйте такой код:

```
$attr_slug = 'color;'
$product->get_attribute( 'pa_' . $attr_slug );
```